# How to implement an algorithm to merge two heaps with n=2^k number of elements in O (k) time?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, merge, heap, top-down

However, I don't even know what this problem means.

This only takes a minimum time of O (n) to just merge the two sorted arrays, I don't know how to merge in O (k) time.

This is a total of three problems associated with it:

> The purpose of this problem is to explore the possibility of building a standard heap efficiently in a top-down manner.
>
> 1. Give a high level description of an algorithm that merges two standard heaps which each contain exactly n = 2^k elements. The algorithm should run in O(k)time.
> 2. Using the subroutine as specified in part 1, give a recursive or iterative algorithm that builds a heap of 2^n elements.
> 3. Write down an equation for the running time of the algorithm specified in part 2, solve it.

Comment: Read up this article: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00264229

Comment: Doing this in logarithmic time means the heaps are represented with linked nodes, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Binomial_heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) or  [Leftist heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leftist_tree).

When n=2^k they all have merge operation in O(k) time.